# Tag start is not closed

Tags: html

In my HTML page, I am getting an error **Tag start is not closed** after the .jpg
Here's the code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<figure>
  <img src="{% static "FLC image.jpg" %}" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
</figure>
```

What is wrong with code ?

Comment: That is not HTML, that is some kind of template. Without knowing exactly what kind I can't be certain (Django's?), but it is likely the template language you are using is enforcing XML syntax (i.e. every opening tag needs to have a matching closing tag, or be an empty tag). Change to `<img.... />`, or add `</img>`.

Comment: try using this  <img src="{% static "FLC image.jpg" %}" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228"/>

Comment: @KevinWong It works now but there is still a red line indicating error after the image name

Comment: Ermm, since I not sure what IDE you are working on, but if you run or save, the web page got render nicely?

Answer (score 1):

You can close the image tag. Try the below code.

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<figure>
  <img src="{% static "FLC image.jpg" %}" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228"/>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't affect the loading of the page, its because of PyCharm IDE. You can still run the runserver command and get the desired output.

If you are using the closing tags then your error will be gone but you wont get the desired output.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    </img {% static "FLC image.jpg" %}" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
```

(or)

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
    <img {% static "FLC image.jpg" %}" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228" />
```

If you are using recent versions of Django try replacing **{% load staticfiles %}** with
**{ %load static % }**

So finally use the below code to get your desired result

```
{% load static %}
    <img {% static "FLC image.jpg" %}" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228" >
```